# difference between np.zeros((1, n)) and np.zeros(n)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand the difference between `np.zeros((1, n))` and `np.zeros(n)`

```
row_vector = np.zeros((1, n))
vector = np.zeros(n)

print('Shape of row_vector: {0}'.format(row_vector.shape))
print('Shape of vector:     {0}'.format(vector.shape))
```

Output is without one extra bracket

```
Contents of row_vector:
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

Contents of vector - Note the number of brackets compared to row_vector:
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Secondly, if I have to add them, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

It simply boils down to the number of dimensions of the array or tensor. The `row_vector` is a 2 dimensional array, while `vector` is a 1 dimensional array.

You can easily verify this by calling the `ndim` attribute.
e.g.

```
>>> row_vector.ndim()
2
>>> vector.ndim()
1
```

---

This additional dimension is very useful when working with tensor focused libraries such as TensorFlow and PyTorch.

Comment: How is it useful? Do those libraries not broadcast?

Comment: I will try to explain using an example. Suppose you are trying to transform a tensor(array) using the methods available in TensorFlow or PyTorch. A lot of these transformation functions require a fixed shape. For instance if you are working with images the the tensor dimensions should be [batch_size, color_channels, height, width]. The dimensions of one grey scale image would be [1, H, W]. To transform this image the batch_size dimensions need to be added.

Comment: So no broadcasting

Comment: Yes and No, forgive the expression. When using certain predefined modules, there is no broadcasting during input. But when you are using binary operators with tensor operands there is  broadcasting.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm just being lazy about RTFMing. +1 for mentioning a usecase where it actually makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that one is a 1D array, the other 2D. You can see this by printing the `x.ndim` attribute or `len(x.shape)`.

That being said, for many practical purposes there is no difference. [Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) aligns dimensions on the right edge, so you can add the two arrays directly using the `+`operator:

```
s = vector + row_vector
```

The result will be 2D, with shape `(1, n)`.

There would be a big difference if the shapes were `(n,)` and `(n, 1)`. Broadcasting would again align the shapes on the right, which would make the sum an outer sum of shape `(n, n)`.

You can perform an outer sum on the existing arrays by accessing a [view](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-view) with a unit axis using [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis):

```
vector[:, np.newaxis] + row_vector
```

Or

```
vector + row_vector[:, np.newaxis]
```